# SQL query result to Array

Tags: c#, sql

I have written the following in an attempt to execute a sql query and store the result in an Array:

```
public static ArrayList DbQueryToArry()
        {
            string SqlCString = myConnString;
            SqlConnection connection = null;

            ArrayList valuesList = new ArrayList();

            connection = new SqlConnection(SqlCString);
            connection.Open();

            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Select CLIENTNO, ACCOUNT_Purpose from audit.ACCOUNTS_AUDIT", connection);
            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                valuesList.Add(Convert.ToInt32(reader[0].ToString()));
            }
            return valuesList;
        }
```

But running the following

```
var myArray = DbQueryToArry();
Console.WriteLine(myArray.ToString());
```

Does not return the query result..

Comment: What does it return instead?

Comment: Review note: `Convert.ToInt32(reader[0].ToString())` is always a bad pattern.  If `CLIENTNO` is an integer, use `(int)reader[0]` or `reader.GetInt32(0)`. If it's a string storing a numeric value, it probably shouldn't be convert to an integer at all; use `(string)reader[0]` or `reader.GetString(0)`.

Comment: Thanks madreflection, that was defiantly required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to join them manually with [`string.Join`](http://String.Join%20Method) or something similar:

> Concatenates the elements of a specified array or the members of a
> collection, using the specified separator between each element or
> member.

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",",myArray.ToArray()));
```

The reason why your version doesnt work is because, [`Console.Writeline`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.writeline?view=netframework-4.7.2) has a bunch of overloads for different types, however it falls back to [`WriteLine(Object)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.writeline?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Console_WriteLine_System_Object_) when it can't find a specific resolution match.

The source code to `WriteLine(Object value)` is as follows (which can be found [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/textwriter.cs,aedbc5e502007cf7)).

```
public virtual void WriteLine(Object value) {
   if (value==null) {
      WriteLine();
   }
   else {
      // Call WriteLine(value.ToString), not Write(Object), WriteLine().
      // This makes calls to WriteLine(Object) atomic.
      IFormattable f = value as IFormattable;
      if (f != null)
         WriteLine(f.ToString(null, FormatProvider));
      else
         WriteLine(value.ToString());
   }
}
```

Notice how it calls `value.ToString()` ?

[Object.ToString Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.tostring?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Returns a string that represents the current object.
>
> **Remarks**
>
> Object.ToString is the major formatting method in the .NET Framework.
> It converts an object to its string representation so that it is
> suitable for display.

An `ArrayList` has no overload to ToString() that would be able to anticipate what you want to show, so it relies on the default.

[The default Object.ToString() method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.tostring?view=netframework-4.7.2#Default)

> The default implementation of the ToString method returns the fully
> qualified name of the type of the Object

Which brings me to my next point, don't use `ArrayList`, Use a generic array `int[]` or `List<int>` you will find it much more fun and rewarding (**fun level 100**)

Comment: Thanks Michael, I don't want to use int[] or List<int> as my query my return strings as well. What would be the appropriate solution here ?

Comment: @entrup If your query may return other types, you have a design problem and heading down the wrong path. For starters `Convert.ToInt32(reader[0].ToString())` will throw an error instantly.

Comment: So what is the best way to make it generic and able to handle both int and string returned values ?

Comment: @entrup this is seeming like another question